# Display file (PDF/TXT) on form brought from Database in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filecontentresult

I want to display file on my form using MVC.

I am bringing a **Byte[]** array data from the Database, and using **FileContentResult** I am converting it into a file.I want to now display this file on my page for viewing . How can it be acheived. What code to write in my **View**  for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Razor, rendering a text file can be done as simple as:

```
<div>
    @(new System.IO.StreamReader("myFile.txt")).ReadToEnd()
</div>
```

For PDF files, you'll have to find a third-party component to convert to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use FileContentResult, that is something generally used for providing the raw file.

In theory though there is nothing different in using any other url

```
<img src="@Html.ActionLink("View","Image",{id = Model.key})" />
```

Or you can provide that link in a pdf reference, or as a stylesheet etc.